# Cannot Install jdeveloper SOA suite

Tags: jdeveloper

I'm trying to install jdeveloper SOA Suite version 12.2.1.4.0 using the Quickstart installation files but no matter what I do the java installation package fails without any meaningful error messages. This is the entire log;

2023-02-07 10:01:26,761 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Launcher log file is C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\launcher2023-02-07_10-01-26AM.log.
2023-02-07 10:01:26,761 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher - Running jar: C:\Java\bin\fmw_12.2.1.4.0_soa_quickstart.jar
2023-02-07 10:01:26,827 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Extracting to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp.
2023-02-07 10:01:26,844 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Extracting the installer . . .
2023-02-07 10:01:34,921 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Finished self extraction to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp.
2023-02-07 10:01:34,967 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Using the parameter file: C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\install\win64\oraparam.ini
2023-02-07 10:01:34,986 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Checking if CPU speed is above 300 MHz
2023-02-07 10:01:34,986 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - .   Actual 2803
2023-02-07 10:01:34,987 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils -     Passed
2023-02-07 10:01:34,987 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors
2023-02-07 10:01:35,220 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - .   Actual 4294967296
2023-02-07 10:01:35,220 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils -     Passed
2023-02-07 10:01:35,220 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Checking swap space: must be greater than 512 MB
2023-02-07 10:01:35,220 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils -     Passed
2023-02-07 10:01:35,220 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Checking if this platform requires a 64-bit JVM
2023-02-07 10:01:35,220 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - .   Actual 64
2023-02-07 10:01:35,220 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils -     Passed (64-bit not required)
2023-02-07 10:01:35,220 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Checking temp space: must be greater than 300 MB
2023-02-07 10:01:35,220 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - .   Actual 882830 MB
2023-02-07 10:01:35,220 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils -     Passed
2023-02-07 10:01:35,220 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Preparing to launch the Oracle Universal Installer from C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM
2023-02-07 10:01:35,220 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.nlsoramapping.jrf\19.3.0.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:35,270 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.nlsrtl.jrf\19.3.0.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:35,287 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.glcm.logging\1.6.4.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:35,303 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.glcm.comdev\7.8.4.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:35,303 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.glcm.dependency\1.8.4.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:35,319 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.glcm.xmldh\3.4.4.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:35,320 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.glcm.wizard\7.8.4.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:35,353 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.jse.dms\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:35,353 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.jrf.dms.common\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,211 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.org.apache.ant.ant.bundle\1.10.5.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,221 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.org.apache.commons.commons.compress\1.9.0.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,259 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.jrf.dms\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,259 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.bali.share\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,275 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.bali.jewt\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,291 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.bali.ice\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,306 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.help.share\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,322 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.help.ohj\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,322 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.fmw.common.wizard.resources\12.2.1.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,338 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.xdk.jrf.xmlparserv2\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,375 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.xdk.jrf\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,391 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.glcm.encryption\2.7.4.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,402 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.java.xml.bind\2.3.0.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,402 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.java.activation\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,419 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.glcm.opatch.common.api\13.9.4.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\OPatch succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,502 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.nginst.common\13.9.4.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oui succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,586 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.nginst.core\13.9.4.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oui succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,602 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.nginst.core\13.9.4.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup2.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,619 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.nginst.core\13.9.4.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup3.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oui succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,619 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.nginst.thirdparty\13.9.4.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,635 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.jaxb.tools\2.3.0.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,660 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.jaxb.impl\2.3.0.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,660 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.jaxb.core\2.3.0.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,707 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.swd.opatch\13.9.4.2.1\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\OPatch succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,707 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.as.install.common.help\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oui succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,723 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.as.install.common.help\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup2.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oui succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,738 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.as.install.common.prerequisite.files\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oui succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,776 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.as.install.ui.framework\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oui succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,792 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.http_client\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,823 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.as.install.soaquickstart\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oui succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,854 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.as.install.soa.prerequisite\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oui succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,861 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.glcm.opatchauto.core\13.9.4.2.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\OPatch succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,876 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.glcm.opatchauto.fmw\13.9.4.2.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\OPatch succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,892 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.glcm.fmw.chghost\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,908 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.bali.ewt\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,935 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.odsi.xquery\12.1.3.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,935 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.as.install.onlinedoc.shortcut\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oui succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,961 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.nginst.common\13.9.4.0.0\DataFiles\filegroup3.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oui succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,969 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.as.install.ui.framework\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup2.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oui succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,969 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unzip of C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl2373027831237471875.tmp\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.glcm.fmw.chghost\12.2.1.4.0\DataFiles\filegroup2.jar to C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oracle_common succeeded.
2023-02-07 10:01:36,985 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - The number of files bootstrapped to the C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM\oui directory is 173.
2023-02-07 10:01:37,934 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Unable to copy the logs to the permanent location: The permanent log directory is unknown (null)..
2023-02-07 10:01:40,098 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils -
The log(s) can be found here: C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM.
2023-02-07 10:01:40,098 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher - Exiting launcher, result: 0

I've tried installing multiple different versions of java and tried having the installation files in different directories (e.g. c:/tmp and c:/temp and even just in the root of the c drive).

Command prompt is definitely being run in administrator mode and I have full admin rights to the machine.

I was expecting the Oracle Jdev installer to launch after the java script had completed.

Comment: Have you checked the logs at The log(s) can be found here: C:\Users\aan3484\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2023-02-07_10-01-26AM?